# Cefsharp, how can i modify the response data when load Url

Tags: cefsharp

when I load a url by cef,  the browser will get many html/js/css/pictures, 
I want to modify the htmlsource,  or replace the pic/css, or modify some functions of the js.
and I have try the IResponseFilter ,it can capture the response data, but it can't modify them . 
I found the SchemeHandlers and IResourceHandler maybe ok, but there isn't a good example about how to work well . So  how can I modify them before they show? ?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-handling You can modify the response data with an IResponseFilter.

Comment: thank you  i will try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261938/1723335

Answer (score 1):

In this sample, If your *request* url was **cefsharp.test** then the *response* will be **Welcome to CefSharp!** :

```
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceHandler GetResourceHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
    {
        //ResourceHandler has many static methods for dealing with Streams, 
        // byte[], files on disk, strings
        // Alternatively ou can inheir from IResourceHandler and implement
        // a custom behaviour that suites your requirements.
        return ResourceHandler.FromString("Welcome to CefSharp!", mimeType: Cef.GetMimeType("html"));
    }
}

public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        //Only intercept specific Url's
        if (request.Url == "http://cefsharp.test/" || request.Url == "https://cefsharp.test/")
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
        }

        //Default behaviour, url will be loaded normally.
        return null;
    }
}

browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```